# Can't login a user using bcrypt (dyld: Symbol not found)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, bcrypt

When I try to login a user using bcrypt.compare to compare passwords, this error message show up in my terminal.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN4node19GetCurrentEventLoopEPN2v87IsolateE
  Referenced from: /pathTo/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN4node19GetCurrentEventLoopEPN2v87IsolateE
  Referenced from: /pathTo/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I am using node.js and express.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's how I've solve it. If this happen to you, you might try to install the bcryptjs package (`yarn add bcryptjs`) and replace:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");`
```

by:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
```

Hope it will work for you too!

Comment: The reason for bcrypt failing and bcryptjs working (in some cases) is that the bcrypt package has non js dependencies like Python 2 which will fail if not available while bcryptjs package has no non js dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, too. I didn't want to change bcrypt to bcryptjs. I uninstall bcrypt and installed it again, and the problem was solved.